# Why is "John makes Bob looks short." wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, causative-make

In an imaginary situation where John is 200 cm tall and Bob 190 cm. Bob is still tall but at the side of John, he looks short.

Why is "John makes Bob looks short." wrong? "Bob looks short." and "Bob looks short at the side of John" are right, right?

Comment: ...note that *Bob looks short at the side of John* is not idiomatic. But you could certainly say *Bob looks short **beside / next to / alongside** John.* Also note that plain *Bob looks short* without an explicit contrast to John is a bit weird, regardless of his actual height.

Comment: It was always the infinitive after ***to make***, but centuries ago the infinitive marker *was* included - Psalm 23:2 KJV: *He maketh me **to lie down** in green pastures.*

Comment: Note: "looks" was not a typo.

Comment: Indeed, not a typo in this case, but a mistake. :-) That's exactly the problem with your sentence, that "s".

Comment: Okay, well I've retracted my closevote. We've had a lot of questions about this specific usage point *(You **make** John **do** it, You **hope** John **does** it, Bob **makes** John **do** it, Bob **hopes** John **does** it)*, so in principle it's almost certainly a duplicate. But you've got two perfectly good answers here, so it may as well stand.

Comment: A lot of Germans make similar mistakes, although it's the same in German: "John lässt Bob klein aussehen." also uses the infinitiv and "John lässt Bob klein aussieht." is wrong.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm perfectly happy with the answer from Seowjooheng Singapore. If you're not, why don't *you* post an answer instead of constantly hassling me?

Answer (score 38):

> *John makes Bob looks short.

*make* is a **causative** verb.  [langeek](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/579/causatives) explains:

> The structure of making this type of causative is as follows: Subject + Causative Verb + Object + **non-finite clause**

> A non-finite clause can be formed using these structures:
> **Bare infinitive** clause: a causative verb is followed by an object and then a **bare infinitive**.
> My mom made me **clean** (bare infinitive) my room.

In our case, it should be

> John makes Bob **look** short.

Comment: But as I note in my answer, there are causatives, like *force* and even ***cause***, that do not allow the bare infinitive: *The added weight **caused** the shelf **to sag***.

Answer (score 15):

The expression ***make** someone V* takes the unmarked infinitive form of the verb. It is similar to many others: compare

- John **makes** his son **do** his homework.
- John **watches** his son **play** baseball.
- John **helps** his son **fly** a kite.
- John **hears** his son **enter** the room.

Others require the marked (*to* form of the) infinitive:

- John **tells** his son **to close** the door.
- John **wants** his son **to succeed** in life.
- John **asks** his son **to wash** his hands.
- John **expects** his son **to follow** him into the family business.
- John **forces** his son **to apologize** to the neighbor.

(Note that in this last one, *force* is, like *make* a causative, but an utterance like **John **forces** his son **apologize*** does not work.)

Of course, there are also lots of verbs that take conjugated forms:

- John **hopes** his son **does** well.
- John **thinks** his son **likes** broccoli.
- John **knows** his son **has** allergies.
- John **fears** his son **is** at risk.
- John **imagines** his son **is** happy.

(Note that all of these involve mental states or acts in which John is engaging. But not all verbs describing mental states take the conjugated form: consider the *expects* example above.)

And in case all of that isn’t confusing enough, *helps* can also take the *to* form. Thus, *John helps his son **to fly** a kite* has the same meaning. And then there’s *John **assists** his son **in studying** for the exam*.

Comment: Alternatively:
John **likes** his son behav**ing**.
John **watches** his son play**ing**.

Comment: It _might_ be useful to note that your last group of examples all feature a "dropped that": "*John hopes [that] his son does well*", "*John thinks [that] his son likes broccoli*", etc.

Comment: It’s true, @IlmariKaronen, that they do. And another, essentially identical, point is that the complement of those verbs is a syntactically complete sentence. But those facts wouldn’t help a learner figure out which class any verb fit in. For instance, whether *taught* would take unmarked infinitive, *to* form, or conjugated form.

Comment: make, let, get etc. are causative verbs.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: It's true that those points won't reveal to a learner which class each verb belongs to. But they can help a learner fit the ways that different verbs work into a framework that makes sense. And in my experience as a learner, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all a linguist, but I am bilingual (a native speaker of English who learned Spanish in their 20s), and I suspect that the easiest explanation to understand for speakers of other European languages who want to learn English is as follows:

Most people think of English verbs as lacking many of the grammatical tenses, moods, and voices that are found in most Romance and Germanic languages.  However, this has not always been the case, and Old English had most of the hallmarks of verb/noun inflection that we think of for modern European languages, such as declension of nouns, grammatical gender, etc. In fact, there are some echos of this that found their ways into Modern English.  Early Modern English preserved a distinction between formal and informal second-person pronouns and a richer conjugation of verbs (see, for instance, the King James Bible).

In this case, I suspect that we are looking at one the last vestiges of the subjunctive mood in English.  It has almost disappeared, but a distinction between the declarative and the subjunctive mood still exists for third-person singular subjects.  For regular verbs, instead of adding an "s" to the end of the infinitive, as you would for third-person singular in the declarative mood, you leave the bare infinitive of the verb unchanged (which is the same inflection as for third-person plural declarative).

Suppose, for instance, that I want to warn you that you need to get to work on time.  In Spanish, we would say "es importante que seas puntual" and not "es importante que eres puntual", in English we say "it's important that you be punctual" instead of "it's important that you are punctual".

The subjunctive mood also seems to have a similar usage in English as in Romance languages; you use it to express a normative judgement (e.g., "good", "bad", "important", etc.).  For *causative* verbs, where you are hoping/forcing/wanting/causing/asking/etc. someone to do something, there is a lot of variability: some of these verbs (such as "make") make the verb in the following clause take the subjunctive mood in this case (or at least are inflected the same as if they were in the subjunctive mood), while others cause it to take the declarative mood (such as "hope") and still others require you to use the full infinitive in the following clause (such as "ask", "require", etc.).  I have noticed the same variability in Spanish (where some of these verbs make the following clause have declarative or subjunctive mood or use the infinitive).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple said: there may only be one 's' in this example:

- Bob look***s*** short
- John make***s*** Bob look short

Comment: Can you explain _why_, please? This is an easy way to think about it for native speakers, perhaps, but on ELL, it's probably better to give some deeper explanation.

Comment: Only one of the persons does something here. In the first sentence it is Bob, in the second sentence it is John.